# OAuth [Facebook / Twitter] Pop Up doesn't open when I click on Social Icons + Ionic + Firebase

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic-popup

I followed [this article](http://blog.ionic.io/adding-social-login-with-firebase/) to create OAuth for Ionic App with Firebase as backend service. Was able to bring up the app in Ionic Lab and social icons were visible. But when I click on any icon, nothing happens.

Just know that my code uses `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and I have very minimal knowledge about that. I except a Facebook or Twitter pop-up to show when I click on corresponding icons but it just doesn't seem to.

**I see following error's in console:**

When I click on the Facebook icon:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?
skip_api_login=1&api_key=150011636022826…
&display=popup&locale=en_US&logger_id=fe62445f-81aa-405e-b35f-
80f8fd220707' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

When I click on the Twitter icon:

```
Refused to display 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?
oauth_token=nSzk7gAAAAAAuTInAAABV456ulg' in a frame because an ancestor 
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 
'self' https://tweetdeck.twitter.com https://tdapi-
staging.smf1.twitter.com https://tdapi-staging.atla.twitter.com 
https://tweetdeck.localhost.twitter.com".`
```

**What do I do to rectify this ?**

When I manually do `ionic serve`, app loads in browser and when I click on Facebook icon, I am able to page getting redirected to Facebook login.

PS: I'm just a day old to this Ionic Framework.

Comment: are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik updated question.

Comment: have you set the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in your facebook or twitter app console ?

Comment: I have cloned the project [from GitHub](https://github.com/mhartington/ionic-firebase-auth) as mentioned at the end of article. I think those OAuth redirect URL's are correctly set else it should have failed in browser too, which is not the case it works all fine in broswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found a resolution & posting it as it may help others :**

[GITHub link](https://github.com/mhartington/ionic-firebase-auth) from where i cloned the project. Then go to file [www/js/controllers.js](https://github.com/mhartington/ionic-firebase-auth/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js) where a `$scope.login()` method is present in `DashCtrl`.

```
Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(authMethod).then(function(authData) {
      console.log(authData);
    })
```

This was the snippet which was giving problem, as it is trying to redirect to different page & it ***works fine in browsers*** but ***fails in app/ionic lab or whatever***.

Instead do this if your work is specific to Ionic app version :

```
Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup(authMethod).then(function(authData) {
          // after successfully logging in the user - do your magic stuff here
          console.log(authData);
        });
```